# How can I change the IEEEtran bibstyle language to German?

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, german

I am new so please do not judge me.

I am using Overleaf to create my LaTex documents and would like to use the IEEEtran BibTex style in order to manage my references. Since I am sometimes writing my papers in German I would like to know if there is a way to change the bibstyle to German. Particularly I would like to get rid of the "[Online]. Available:" in the references when quoting a website and replace it by some German text.

My bibliography:

```
@Online{asdf,
  title = {asdf},
  url = {asdf.at},
}
```

How I create the bibliography:

```
\medskip
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

The output in the pdf: [1]   asdf. [Online]. Available: asdf.at

Here I would like to have e.g. "Verfügbar" instead of "Available".

If you need more information feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot, these are hardwired in. You may need to find `IEEEtran.bst` and make you own German version of it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I downloaded the original and just changes the "Available" to "Verfügbar".

Comment: Make sure to save it under another name. And there is probably many more such strings that needs translation.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I will just change everything when it comes up in my literature.

Comment: "when it comes up in my literature" - speaking of experience, chances are astronomical that you will either miss some or need to invest valueable time close to the end of the project with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

This specific text can be edited using the **IEEEtran BST Control**, as described [here](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf).

There are two steps:

1. Add an `IEEEtranBSTCTL` entry to any of the included `.bib` files and edit the `CTLname_url_prefix` property.
   In your case, add this to your `bibliography.bib`:

```tex
IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEBST:Online,
  CTLname_url_prefix = "[Online]. Verfügbar:"
}
```

2. Then, in the main `.tex` file, cite this entry using a special command:

```tex
\bstctlcite{IEEEBST:Online}
```

This must be done before citing other entries.
I recommend adding the `\bstctlcite` right after your `\begin{document}`.
`\bstctlcite` is silent, meaning it does not add any entry to the bibliography and it does not show in the text.